# Mask text Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I wanna format of differents ways a value from textfield.

In a pseudocode it would be like this:

`if length(value) == 2: mask = ##; if length(value) == 3: mask = #.##;`

I made this, but the mask don't change.

```
var maskedKg =
    MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: '#', filter: {"#": RegExp(r'[0-9]')});

switch (controller.text.length) {
    case 2:
      {
        controller.value = maskedKg.updateMask(mask: '##');
        break;
      }
    case 3:
      {
        controller.value = maskedKg.updateMask(mask: '#.##');
        break;
      }
    case 4:
      {
        controller.value = maskedKg.updateMask(mask: '##.##');
        break;
      }
    case 5:
      {
        controller.value = maskedKg.updateMask(mask: '###.##');
        break;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Try using the switch case on onchanged property.

Comment: Just to expand a little on Krish's comment: when you create the TextField you define the controller and can also add a callback for when the text changes (the `onChanged` argument of the constructor). This gets called whenever the text changes, and is the appropriate place to make changes to your mask as you have done in the switch statement